# What are the novel MOOP method?

Tags: constrained-optimization

As you know, the multi-objective optimization methods are developing so fast, i.e.,epsilon constraints. I have a problem that I want to apply the most recent MOOP method for it.
Please tell me the recent methods for solving multi-objective optimisation(MOOP).
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The ones that I know are:*

The Physical Programming (PP) method was suggested by Messac (1996).

The Normal Boundary Intersection (NBI) method was developed by Das and Dennis (1998) and Das (1999).

The Normal Constraint (NC) method by Messac et al. (2003) and Messac and Mattson (2004) represents a modification of the NBI approach

Enhanced Normalized Normal constriant method is also devolved (2008)

Utyuzhnikov et al. (2005, 2009) suggested modifications to the PP method to make it possibly simpler and more flexible for practical applications

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there anything after 2010? @elctricman

Comment: Perhaps there are, But I am not aware of them. I hope others find this question interesting too and add more information about new states of the art. @Jamaisavenir